# This function is reflecting and conflicting with all sub li and sub (a) anchor tag

Tags: jquery

This function is reflecting and conflicting with all sub li and sub (a) anchor tag, so sub anchor tags also got the active class which s not needed, help me out....

```
jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").live('click', function (){ 
  jQuery(".sub_nav").slideUp("fast");
  jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").removeClass("active");  
  jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").slideToggle("slow"); 
  jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  jQuery(".left_navigation ul li a").removeClass("active"); 
  jQuery(this).find("a").addClass("active"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you need click for just `li` and not for its child `a`.

you can do this

```
jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").live('click', function (e){ 
  if (e.target == this){  //<---make it work for just li and not a
   jQuery(".sub_nav").slideUp("fast");
   jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").removeClass("active");  
   jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").slideToggle("slow"); 
   jQuery(this).addClass("active");
   jQuery(".left_navigation ul li a").removeClass("active"); 
   jQuery(this).find("a").addClass("active"); 
  } 
});
```

and i guess  you are using old version of jQuery , since `live()` is deprecated and removed in newer version. so if in case you use latest version, its better to use `on()` instead of `live()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(".left_navigation ul li li").live('click', function (event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").live('click', function (){ 
  jQuery(".sub_nav").slideUp("fast");
  jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").removeClass("active");  
  jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").slideToggle("slow"); 
  jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  jQuery(".left_navigation ul li a").removeClass("active"); 
  jQuery(this).children("a").addClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: yes it resolved "a"  but when i am clicking on sub_nav li then slideToggle is effecting, i think it only work with the parent li neither sub_nav li...

Comment: i still facing one error.... that .slideToggle on current li is not working properly, because on clicking on active li it's reflecting again close and open at the same time, it should be close on second clicking